# I am receiving multiple response on client side

Tags: spring-integration

I am able to read the response from the server but I am getting this message on the client-side "cannot correlate response - no pending reply for cached:localhost:3002:46550:f6234e17-c486-4506-82c8-a757a08ba73d." after a minute, though the server is not sending any message back, From the server-side, I can see this message "Connection lost: " 127.0.0.1" printed out in the log.

```
 @Bean
public AbstractClientConnectionFactory clientConnectionFactory() {  
    TcpNioClientConnectionFactory tcpNioClientConnectionFactory = new TcpNioClientConnectionFactory(host, port);
    tcpNioClientConnectionFactory.setUsingDirectBuffers(true);
    tcpNioClientConnectionFactory.setApplicationEventPublisher(applicationEventPublisher);
    return new CachingClientConnectionFactory(tcpNioClientConnectionFactory, connectionPoolSize);
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel outboundChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "outboundChannel")
public MessageHandler outboundGateway(AbstractClientConnectionFactory clientConnectionFactory) {
    TcpOutboundGateway tcpOutboundGateway = new TcpOutboundGateway();
    tcpOutboundGateway.setConnectionFactory(clientConnectionFactory);
    tcpOutboundGateway.setRemoteTimeout(Long.MAX_VALUE);
    tcpOutboundGateway.setRequestTimeout(5_000);
    return tcpOutboundGateway;
}
```

```
2022-03-22 13:14:46,878 [http-nio-9000-exec-4][][][][][][][] DEBUG org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel - preSend on channel 'bean 'outboundChannel'; defined in: 'class path resource [com/wibmo/aerionpg/config/TcpClientConfig.class]'; from source: 'com.wibmo.aerionpg.config.TcpClientConfig.outboundChannel()'', message: GenericMessage [payload=byte[602], headers={replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@2936326d, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@2936326d, id=062c0c73-addf-e90c-4b80-aebc70ec009b, timestamp=1647935086878}]
2022-03-22 13:14:46,878 [http-nio-9000-exec-4][][][][][][][] DEBUG org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway - bean 'outboundGateway'; defined in: 'class path resource [com/wibmo/aerionpg/config/TcpClientConfig.class]'; from source: 'com.wibmo.aerionpg.config.TcpClientConfig.outboundGateway(org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.AbstractClientConnectionFactory)' received message: GenericMessage [payload=byte[602], headers={replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@2936326d, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@2936326d, id=062c0c73-addf-e90c-4b80-aebc70ec009b, timestamp=1647935086878}]
2022-03-22 13:14:46,879 [http-nio-9000-exec-4][][][][][][][] DEBUG org.springframework.integration.util.SimplePool - Obtained TcpNioConnection:127.0.0.1:6001:54856:37e334df-5c89-4b51-af4f-727d0f484a29 from pool.
2022-03-22 13:14:46,879 [http-nio-9000-exec-4][][][][][][][] DEBUG org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway - Added pending reply Cached:127.0.0.1:6001:54856:37e334df-5c89-4b51-af4f-727d0f484a29
2022-03-22 13:14:46,879 [http-nio-9000-exec-4][][][][][][][] DEBUG org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection - 127.0.0.1:6001:54856:37e334df-5c89-4b51-af4f-727d0f484a29 writing 604
2022-03-22 13:14:46,879 [http-nio-9000-exec-4][][][][][][][] DEBUG org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection - 127.0.0.1:6001:54856:37e334df-5c89-4b51-af4f-727d0f484a29 Message sent GenericMessage [payload=byte[602], headers={replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@2936326d, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@2936326d, id=062c0c73-addf-e90c-4b80-aebc70ec009b, timestamp=1647935086878}]
2022-03-22 13:14:47,382 [pool-2-thread-1][][][][][][][] TRACE org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioClientConnectionFactory - null: Connection is open: 127.0.0.1:6001:54856:37e334df-5c89-4b51-af4f-727d0f484a29
2022-03-22 13:14:47,382 [pool-2-thread-1][][][][][][][] TRACE org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioClientConnectionFactory - Host 127.0.0.1 port 6001 SelectionCount: 1
2022-03-22 13:14:47,382 [pool-2-thread-2][][][][][][][] DEBUG org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection - 127.0.0.1:6001:54856:37e334df-5c89-4b51-af4f-727d0f484a29 Reading...
2022-03-22 13:14:47,382 [pool-2-thread-2][][][][][][][] DEBUG org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection - 127.0.0.1:6001:54856:37e334df-5c89-4b51-af4f-727d0f484a29 Running an assembler
2022-03-22 13:14:47,383 [pool-2-thread-2][][][][][][][] TRACE org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection - Before read: 0/61440
2022-03-22 13:14:47,383 [pool-2-thread-2][][][][][][][] TRACE org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection - After read: 614/61440
2022-03-22 13:14:47,383 [pool-2-thread-2][][][][][][][] TRACE org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection - After flip: 0/614
2022-03-22 13:14:47,383 [pool-2-thread-3][][][][][][][] TRACE org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection - 127.0.0.1:6001:54856:37e334df-5c89-4b51-af4f-727d0f484a29 Nio message assembler running...
2022-03-22 13:14:47,383 [pool-2-thread-3][][][][][][][] TRACE org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection - 127.0.0.1:6001:54856:37e334df-5c89-4b51-af4f-727d0f484a29 checking data avail: 0 pending: true
2022-03-22 13:14:47,383 [pool-2-thread-3][][][][][][][] TRACE org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection - 127.0.0.1:6001:54856:37e334df-5c89-4b51-af4f-727d0f484a29 checking data avail (convert): 0 pending: true
2022-03-22 13:14:47,383 [pool-2-thread-2][][][][][][][] DEBUG org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection - Read 614 into raw buffer
2022-03-22 13:14:47,383 [pool-2-thread-2][][][][][][][] TRACE org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection - 127.0.0.1:6001:54856:37e334df-5c89-4b51-af4f-727d0f484a29 Sending 614 to pipe
2022-03-22 13:14:47,383 [pool-2-thread-3][][][][][][][] DEBUG org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.serializer.ByteArrayCrLfSerializer - Available to read: 614
2022-03-22 13:14:47,383 [pool-2-thread-1][][][][][][][] TRACE org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioClientConnectionFactory - null: Connection is open: 127.0.0.1:6001:54856:37e334df-5c89-4b51-af4f-727d0f484a29
2022-03-22 13:14:47,383 [pool-2-thread-1][][][][][][][] TRACE org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioClientConnectionFactory - Host 127.0.0.1 port 6001 SelectionCount: 0
2022-03-22 13:14:47,383 [pool-2-thread-3][][][][][][][] TRACE org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection - 127.0.0.1:6001:54856:37e334df-5c89-4b51-af4f-727d0f484a29 checking data avail: 0 pending: false
2022-03-22 13:14:47,383 [pool-2-thread-3][][][][][][][] TRACE org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway - onMessage: Cached:127.0.0.1:6001:54856:37e334df-5c89-4b51-af4f-727d0f484a29(GenericMessage [payload=byte[612], headers={ip_tcp_remotePort=6001, ip_connectionId=Cached:127.0.0.1:6001:54856:37e334df-5c89-4b51-af4f-727d0f484a29, ip_actualConnectionId=127.0.0.1:6001:54856:37e334df-5c89-4b51-af4f-727d0f484a29, ip_localInetAddress=/127.0.0.1, ip_address=127.0.0.1, id=f9619787-4d0c-e894-ae05-f2eca0c4a1b4, ip_hostname=127.0.0.1, timestamp=1647935087383}])
2022-03-22 13:14:47,383 [pool-2-thread-3][][][][][][][] TRACE org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection - 127.0.0.1:6001:54856:37e334df-5c89-4b51-af4f-727d0f484a29 checking data avail: 0 pending: false
2022-03-22 13:14:47,383 [pool-2-thread-3][][][][][][][] TRACE org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection - 127.0.0.1:6001:54856:37e334df-5c89-4b51-af4f-727d0f484a29 Nio message assembler exiting... avail: 0
2022-03-22 13:14:47,383 [http-nio-9000-exec-4][][][][][][][] DEBUG org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway - Response GenericMessage [payload=byte[612], headers={ip_tcp_remotePort=6001, ip_connectionId=Cached:127.0.0.1:6001:54856:37e334df-5c89-4b51-af4f-727d0f484a29, ip_actualConnectionId=127.0.0.1:6001:54856:37e334df-5c89-4b51-af4f-727d0f484a29, ip_localInetAddress=/127.0.0.1, ip_address=127.0.0.1, id=f9619787-4d0c-e894-ae05-f2eca0c4a1b4, ip_hostname=127.0.0.1, timestamp=1647935087383}]
2022-03-22 13:14:47,383 [http-nio-9000-exec-4][][][][][][][] DEBUG org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway - Removed pending reply Cached:127.0.0.1:6001:54856:37e334df-5c89-4b51-af4f-727d0f484a29
2022-03-22 13:14:47,383 [http-nio-9000-exec-4][][][][][][][] DEBUG org.springframework.integration.util.SimplePool - Releasing TcpNioConnection:127.0.0.1:6001:54856:37e334df-5c89-4b51-af4f-727d0f484a29 back to the pool
2022-03-22 13:14:47,383 [http-nio-9000-exec-4][][][][][][][] DEBUG org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel - postSend (sent=true) on channel 'bean 'outboundChannel'; defined in: 'class path resource [com/wibmo/aerionpg/config/TcpClientConfig.class]'; from source: 'com.wibmo.aerionpg.config.TcpClientConfig.outboundChannel()'', message: GenericMessage [payload=byte[602], headers={replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@2936326d, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@2936326d, id=062c0c73-addf-e90c-4b80-aebc70ec009b, timestamp=1647935086878}]
2022-03-22 13:15:47,383 [pool-2-thread-1][][][][][][][] TRACE org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioClientConnectionFactory - null: Connection is open: 127.0.0.1:6001:54856:37e334df-5c89-4b51-af4f-727d0f484a29
2022-03-22 13:15:47,383 [pool-2-thread-1][][][][][][][] TRACE org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioClientConnectionFactory - Host 127.0.0.1 port 6001 SelectionCount: 1
2022-03-22 13:15:47,384 [pool-2-thread-3][][][][][][][] DEBUG org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection - 127.0.0.1:6001:54856:37e334df-5c89-4b51-af4f-727d0f484a29 Reading...
2022-03-22 13:15:47,384 [pool-2-thread-3][][][][][][][] DEBUG org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection - 127.0.0.1:6001:54856:37e334df-5c89-4b51-af4f-727d0f484a29 Running an assembler
2022-03-22 13:15:47,384 [pool-2-thread-3][][][][][][][] TRACE org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection - Before read: 0/61440
2022-03-22 13:15:47,384 [pool-2-thread-3][][][][][][][] TRACE org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection - After read: 14/61440
2022-03-22 13:15:47,384 [pool-2-thread-3][][][][][][][] TRACE org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection - After flip: 0/14
2022-03-22 13:15:47,384 [pool-2-thread-3][][][][][][][] DEBUG org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection - Read 14 into raw buffer
2022-03-22 13:15:47,384 [pool-2-thread-3][][][][][][][] TRACE org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection - 127.0.0.1:6001:54856:37e334df-5c89-4b51-af4f-727d0f484a29 Sending 14 to pipe
2022-03-22 13:15:47,384 [pool-2-thread-1][][][][][][][] TRACE org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioClientConnectionFactory - null: Connection is open: 127.0.0.1:6001:54856:37e334df-5c89-4b51-af4f-727d0f484a29
2022-03-22 13:15:47,384 [pool-2-thread-1][][][][][][][] TRACE org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioClientConnectionFactory - Host 127.0.0.1 port 6001 SelectionCount: 0
2022-03-22 13:15:47,384 [pool-2-thread-1][][][][][][][] TRACE org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioClientConnectionFactory - null: Connection is open: 127.0.0.1:6001:54856:37e334df-5c89-4b51-af4f-727d0f484a29
2022-03-22 13:15:47,384 [pool-2-thread-1][][][][][][][] TRACE org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioClientConnectionFactory - Host 127.0.0.1 port 6001 SelectionCount: 1
2022-03-22 13:15:47,384 [pool-2-thread-2][][][][][][][] TRACE org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection - 127.0.0.1:6001:54856:37e334df-5c89-4b51-af4f-727d0f484a29 Nio message assembler running...
2022-03-22 13:15:47,384 [pool-2-thread-2][][][][][][][] TRACE org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection - 127.0.0.1:6001:54856:37e334df-5c89-4b51-af4f-727d0f484a29 checking data avail: 14 pending: false
2022-03-22 13:15:47,384 [pool-2-thread-2][][][][][][][] TRACE org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection - 127.0.0.1:6001:54856:37e334df-5c89-4b51-af4f-727d0f484a29 checking data avail (convert): 14 pending: false
2022-03-22 13:15:47,384 [pool-2-thread-2][][][][][][][] DEBUG org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.serializer.ByteArrayCrLfSerializer - Available to read: 14
2022-03-22 13:15:47,385 [pool-2-thread-2][][][][][][][] TRACE org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection - 127.0.0.1:6001:54856:37e334df-5c89-4b51-af4f-727d0f484a29 checking data avail: 0 pending: false
2022-03-22 13:15:47,385 [pool-2-thread-2][][][][][][][] TRACE org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway - onMessage: Cached:127.0.0.1:6001:54856:37e334df-5c89-4b51-af4f-727d0f484a29(GenericMessage [payload=byte[12], headers={ip_tcp_remotePort=6001, ip_connectionId=Cached:127.0.0.1:6001:54856:37e334df-5c89-4b51-af4f-727d0f484a29, ip_actualConnectionId=127.0.0.1:6001:54856:37e334df-5c89-4b51-af4f-727d0f484a29, ip_localInetAddress=/127.0.0.1, ip_address=127.0.0.1, id=b9f23b01-6816-65f1-c1e9-f4cf1c21bccc, ip_hostname=127.0.0.1, timestamp=1647935147385}])
2022-03-22 13:15:47,385 [pool-2-thread-2][][][][][][][] ERROR org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway - Cannot correlate response - no pending reply for Cached:127.0.0.1:6001:54856:37e334df-5c89-4b51-af4f-727d0f484a29
2022-03-22 13:15:47,386 [pool-2-thread-2][][][][][][][] TRACE org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection - 127.0.0.1:6001:54856:37e334df-5c89-4b51-af4f-727d0f484a29 checking data avail: 0 pending: false
2022-03-22 13:15:47,386 [pool-2-thread-2][][][][][][][] TRACE org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection - 127.0.0.1:6001:54856:37e334df-5c89-4b51-af4f-727d0f484a29 Nio message assembler exiting... avail: 0
2022-03-22 13:15:47,386 [pool-2-thread-3][][][][][][][] DEBUG org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection - 127.0.0.1:6001:54856:37e334df-5c89-4b51-af4f-727d0f484a29 Reading...
2022-03-22 13:15:47,386 [pool-2-thread-3][][][][][][][] DEBUG org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection - 127.0.0.1:6001:54856:37e334df-5c89-4b51-af4f-727d0f484a29 Running an assembler
2022-03-22 13:15:47,386 [pool-2-thread-2][][][][][][][] TRACE org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection - 127.0.0.1:6001:54856:37e334df-5c89-4b51-af4f-727d0f484a29 Nio message assembler running...
2022-03-22 13:15:47,386 [pool-2-thread-2][][][][][][][] TRACE org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection - 127.0.0.1:6001:54856:37e334df-5c89-4b51-af4f-727d0f484a29 checking data avail: 0 pending: true
2022-03-22 13:15:47,386 [pool-2-thread-2][][][][][][][] TRACE org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection - 127.0.0.1:6001:54856:37e334df-5c89-4b51-af4f-727d0f484a29 checking data avail (convert): 0 pending: true
2022-03-22 13:15:47,386 [pool-2-thread-3][][][][][][][] TRACE org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection - Before read: 0/61440
2022-03-22 13:15:47,386 [pool-2-thread-3][][][][][][][] DEBUG org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.CachingClientConnectionFactory$CachedConnection - Connection Cached:127.0.0.1:6001:54856:37e334df-5c89-4b51-af4f-727d0f484a29 has already been released
2022-03-22 13:15:47,387 [pool-2-thread-3][][][][][][][] TRACE org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection - Published: TcpConnectionCloseEvent [source=TcpNioConnection:127.0.0.1:6001:54856:37e334df-5c89-4b51-af4f-727d0f484a29], [factory=unknown, connectionId=127.0.0.1:6001:54856:37e334df-5c89-4b51-af4f-727d0f484a29] **CLOSED**
2022-03-22 13:15:47,387 [pool-2-thread-3][][][][][][][] TRACE org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection - After read: 0/61440
2022-03-22 13:15:47,387 [pool-2-thread-3][][][][][][][] TRACE org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection - After flip: 0/0
2022-03-22 13:15:47,387 [pool-2-thread-3][][][][][][][] DEBUG org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection - Read 0 into raw buffer
2022-03-22 13:15:47,387 [pool-2-thread-3][][][][][][][] TRACE org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection - 127.0.0.1:6001:54856:37e334df-5c89-4b51-af4f-727d0f484a29 Sending 0 to pipe
2022-03-22 13:15:47,387 [pool-2-thread-2][][][][][][][] TRACE org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection - 127.0.0.1:6001:54856:37e334df-5c89-4b51-af4f-727d0f484a29 checking data avail: 0 pending: false
2022-03-22 13:15:47,387 [pool-2-thread-2][][][][][][][] TRACE org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection - 127.0.0.1:6001:54856:37e334df-5c89-4b51-af4f-727d0f484a29 checking data avail: 0 pending: false
2022-03-22 13:15:47,387 [pool-2-thread-2][][][][][][][] TRACE org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection - 127.0.0.1:6001:54856:37e334df-5c89-4b51-af4f-727d0f484a29 Nio message assembler exiting... avail: 0
2022-03-22 13:15:47,387 [pool-2-thread-3][][][][][][][] TRACE org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway - onMessage: Cached:127.0.0.1:6001:54856:37e334df-5c89-4b51-af4f-727d0f484a29(ErrorMessage [payload=java.io.EOFException: Connection is closed, headers={id=78de443c-cf7a-5e4d-89bc-0b8c4027b5a5, ip_connectionId=Cached:127.0.0.1:6001:54856:37e334df-5c89-4b51-af4f-727d0f484a29, timestamp=1647935147387, ip_actualConnectionId=127.0.0.1:6001:54856:37e334df-5c89-4b51-af4f-727d0f484a29}])
```

Comment: The server must be sending a second response; I suggest you turn on DEBUG logging for `org.springframework.integration` to see socket activity; if you can't figure it out, post the logs someplace.

Comment: @GaryRussell, Logs added, looks like there is a second response, can you please confirm?

Comment: @GaryRussell How can I add one more message handler here? I am using gateways here, Sorry, I am new to spring integration.

Comment: I added an example to the answer; I used the Java DSL because it is much easier than declaring discrete beans.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the server is closing the socket 1 minute later, but before doing that, it is sending a message - 14 bytes; presumably 12 bytes + `\r\n`, given your configuration.

Starting with version 5.4, you can add an `unsolicitedMessageChannel` to the outbound gateway; these extra messages will be sent there, instead of generating that log message.

```java
/**
 * Set the channel name for unsolicited incoming messages, or late replies.
 * @param unsolicitedMessageChannelName the channel name.
 * @since 5.4
 */
public void setUnsolicitedMessageChannelName(String unsolicitedMessageChannelName) {
    this.unsolicitedMessageChannelName = unsolicitedMessageChannelName;
}

/**
 * Set the channel for unsolicited incoming messages, or late replies.
 * @param unsolicitedMessageChannel the channel.
 * @since 5.4
 */
public void setUnsolicitedMessageChannel(MessageChannel unsolicitedMessageChannel) {
    this.unsolicitedMessageChannel = unsolicitedMessageChannel;
}
```

You can add  message handler (e.g. `@ServiceActivator`) to consume from that channel to see what the content is, or you can set it to `"nullChannel"` to just discard it.

**EDIT**

Here is an example, using the Java DSL:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So71552834Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So71552834Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow clientFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Gate.class)
                .handle(Tcp.outboundGateway(Tcp.netClient("localhost", 1234))
                        .unsolictedMessageChannelName("unsolicited"))
                .get();
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "unsolicited")
    public void handleUnsolicited(String in) {
        System.out.println("Unsolicited response: " + in);
    }

    // emulate the server side.

    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow serverFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Tcp.inboundGateway(Tcp.netServer(1234)))
                .transform(Transformers.objectToString())
                .<String>handle((p, h) -> p.toUpperCase())
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow serverOut(AbstractServerConnectionFactory scf) {
        return f -> f.handle(Tcp.outboundAdapter(scf));
    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner runner(Gate gate, IntegrationFlow serverOut, AbstractServerConnectionFactory scf) {
        return args -> {
            System.out.println(new String(gate.exchange("test")));
            System.out.println("Hit enter to send an unsolicited message");
            System.in.read();
            String id = scf.getOpenConnectionIds().iterator().next();
            serverOut.getInputChannel().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("what's this?")
                    .setHeader(IpHeaders.CONNECTION_ID, id)
                    .build());
        };
    }

}

interface Gate {

    byte[] exchange(String out);

}
```

```
TEST
Hit enter to send an unsolicited message

Unsolicited response: what's this?
```